# alternative to adding a box initially covering content that actually helps users

Tags: content

I made a photo collage editor system on my site and I tried to made the page with a lot of text so that users know what is going on.

This is the URL if anyone is wondering: http://new.clubcatcher.com/collage

Anyways, what happens to new users is that a "sticky" box appears over content at the bottom right reminding guests where they can go if they need extensive help on making a collage. They can click the "no thanks" button in the box to remove it completely.

Now I'm starting to think my income went down again because of this box. Maybe google is thinking that I'm just playing games with people by blocking content, yet I'm only doing it to try to help people. This is the only section of the site where that box would exist. The only other times a box like that exists is if the user decides to go through the tutorial.

As for box implementation, the box is hidden by default via CSS then javascript checks for a special cookie and if it is unset, the box appears, otherwise it stays hidden.

I still want to point out to users that such tutorial exists, but somehow I feel the way I'm doing it is frustrating google.

What would be another way I can advertise the existence of the tutorial from within the same page where even the dumbest person on the planet can still find it without frustrating google, any user, or any other search engine?

Comment: Dumbest person on the planet?? You mean Google? Just kidding!! Just a joke and not an opinion. Please don't beat the snot out of me G. Seriously. Just a joke.

Comment: How did your income go down?   You lost rankings and organic traffic, or you lost money on the AdSense side?

Comment: I lost money on the adsense side.